# Create Bitmap of a listview completely which is not visible on the screen.

Tags: android, image, bitmap

I am trying to create a bit map of a list view, where the entire listview is not visible on the screen. I am using

Bitmap mBitmap = fullView.getDrawingCache();

to create bitmap. It works fine for the part of listview that is visible on the screen but, not for the part that is not.I would like to know if a bitmap of a listview can be created without having to display it completely on the screen. All suggestions/ solutions are appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [List View using bitmap](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864334/list-view-using-bitmap)

Comment: @AedonEtLIRA It's the same question asked by the same person!

Comment: Ive added a answer here
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6864334/list-view-using-bitmap/7304595#7304595