# Android magnifier

Tags: android, graphics

I developing an android where I am desperate need of magnifier,My scenario is I have rotating bitmap on canvas and I need magnifier on top that.(i-e when the bitmap rotates we need to magnify the certain area)

Regards
Altaf

Comment: so what is the problem and what have you tried?

Comment: I have rotating a bitmap on canvas and I need magnifier on specific location and during the rotation when we whatever comes under the magnifier it magnifying it this my problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure, but I think you could use matrix and createbitmap.
The idea is basically going to capture a rectangle area from the screen/bitmap, write it as a new one, and then draw the bitmap in a rectangle to blow it up.
This might help.
[Android: Bitmap from oversized view](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9296782/android-bitmap-from-oversized-view)